# Optical physics and principle of reversibility

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, refraction, geometric-optics, time-reversal-symmetry

I know that if a ray is incident at the medium boundary at critical angle, the ray after refraction moves towards the medium boundary. So, is it possible that if a ray is passed through the medium boundary, it will deviate towards the denser medium? if not then can it be called an exception of principle of reversibility of light rays. Please help me through this paradox.

Comment: no thats not what i am saying

Comment: we all know the principle of reversibility of path of light

Comment: so when a light ray is incident at a point at angle equal to critical angle it grazes the surface

Comment: so i am just asking that by the principle of reversibility can we reverse the path i.e will a ray grazing the surface move towards the denser medium at that very point

Comment: or this is an possible exception

Comment: just let me know if i could help in clarifying my question any further

Comment: That is precisely what the linked duplicate is asking, and the answers there address it from a variety of viewpoints.

Comment: oh yes i am really sorry i didn`t see the question thoroughly